# How to make "Display in Menu" default setting OFF in DNN

Tags: settings, dotnetnuke, default

Is there a way to have the non-display option on page creation in DNN set to OFF as default?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page that has all of the settings that you want, then save a page template for that page.  The page template can be used to create additional pages.  (There is a place to specify the page template in the Create New Page UI.)

Comment: Thank you so much Joe I really appreciate it.  I will give it a go,  looks like a good workaround.  I was asked another question on defaults which you may also be able to answer.  Is there a way in search that it automatically searches for exact matches only as default? I have a client who is trying to do this, not sure if one of the add-on packages maybe even has this facility.  Have a great day and thanks

Comment: Please use another thread for another question, thank you.